# Block body and expression body functions showing different behaviour in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, intellij-idea, return, boolean

When i use a block body function to compare two numbers the compiler throws error if i do not particularly specify the return type. You can see in below function that if i don't specify return type as `Boolean` it throws error

```
fun compare(a:Int,b:Int):Boolean
{
    val c= a==b
    return c
}
```

On the other hand if i use an expression body function and don't mention any return type, compiler throws no error and works fine. Like in the below example

```
fun compare(a: Int, b: Int) = a == b
```

What is reason behind this. I understand that compiler tries to figure out return types on seeing argument's type but isn't this applicable to both syntax ? Why both are working differently ?

Comment: _"Functions with block body must always specify return types explicitly, unless it's intended for them to return Unit, in which case it is optional.
"_  (See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#explicit-return-types). Your first example is a function with a block body. Your second example is not (it is a single expression function).

Comment: So that means kotlin will infer return types for only expression body functions and not the block body ones ?

Comment: Yes. Probably for reasons of code clarity. If you use a block body, presumably there's more than one line of code, so you can't tell at a glance what the return type is if it's not stated. And without this rule, you couldn't rely on seeing no return type as meaning it doesn't return anything but Unit.

Comment: okay Got it. Thanks bros

Comment: @Michael You could make that into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is available in documentation already. According to kotlin docs Functions with block body must always specify return types explicitly, unless it's intended for them to return `Unit`, in which case it is optional. Kotlin does not infer return types for functions with block bodies because such functions may have complex control flow in the body, and the return type will be non-obvious to the reader (and sometimes even for the compiler).